# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when using checkboxes

Tags: php

I am trying to update check boxes on a form and keep getting the error message "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

I have tried setting up the array and can't work out why it's not working.

Here is my code so far.

```
$health_disability_problem_if_yes = isset($_POST['health_disability_problem_if_yes']) ? json_encode($_POST['health_disability_problem_if_yes']) : $contact['health_disability_problem_if_yes'];


    <?php
    $health_disability_problem_array = json_decode($contact['health_disability_problem_if_yes']);
    ?>

<input type="checkbox" name="health_disability_problem_if_yes[]" value="Hearing impairment" <?php 
        foreach($health_disability_problem_array as $hdpa){
            if($hdpa=="Hearing impairment"){ echo 'checked'; } 
        }
        ?>>
```

Comment: foreach can only handle arrays (or better said: iterables). Providing a JSON-string won't work.

Comment: Where do you even define `$health_disability_problem_array`? The posted code only defines `$health_disability_problem_if_yes`. Are you using the wrong variable? If so, then fix that and refer to the first comment by @MarkusZeller. If not, please show us what it contains.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to add the code in where I am defying the $